# How to replace method invocation with mock?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I have a class with two methods. I want to replace invocation of second method with expected result.

Here is my class under test

```
public class A {
    public int methodOne() {
        return methodTwo(1);
    }

    public int methodTwo(int param) {
        // corresponding logic replaced for demo
        throw new RuntimeException("Wrong invocation!");
    }
}
```

And test

```
public class ATest {
    @Test
    public void test() {
        final A a = spy(new A());
        when(a.methodTwo(anyInt())).thenReturn(10);
        a.methodOne();
        verify(a, times(1)).methodTwo(anyInt());
    }
}
```

Why I'm get an exception when start the test?

Comment: What is the exception you are getting?

Comment: `java.lang.RuntimeException: Wrong invocation!` But I need to return `10` instead of RuntimeException. I need to mock the second method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things that will help you here.  First, from the documentation it seems you need to use the `do*()` api with `spy()` objects.  Second, to call the "real" method you need to declare it specifically using `doCallRealMethod()`

Here's the updated test that should work for you:

```
public class ATest {
    @Test
    public void test() {
        final A a = spy(new A());
        doReturn(10).when(a).methodTwo(anyInt());
        doCallRealMethod().when(a).methodOne();
        a.methodOne();
        verify(a, times(1)).methodTwo(anyInt());
    }
}
```

Comment: But if I want to use spy object, in this case what should I do?

Comment: Actually I need a real object of `A`.